# Finding spanning set of a nullspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I figured I'd take the RREF of the matrix and set it equal to zero. Confused as to what I am supposed to do from here. Any guidance would be great.

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nullspace of $A$ is defined by all vectors $x$ for which the two formulas:
$$6x_1+4x_2+4x_3+2x_4=0$$
and
$$-6x_1-4x_2-4x_3-2x_4=0$$
hold. Since the two formulas are equivalent, you just need one to determine the nullspace.

Now, of all vectors satisfying the first equation, what is their basis? It's clear you need $3$ vectors, they need to be independent, and all need to satisfy the equation. My suggestion is: Set one of the components to $1$ and as many of the others to $0$. Get one vector. Repeat.

Comment: I guess I am still confused. For every other one I did, I reduced it and set it to zero. Solved and replaced vectors with necessary free variables. The fact that the equations are the same isn't making sense to me.

Comment: The first equation is satisfied if and only if the second is satisfied. This means you can ignore one of them. Just solve for one of the equations and you will solve for the second.


Another way of thinking is that you can, by adding the first row of the matrix to the second, reduce the matrix to
$$\begin{bmatrix}6&4&4&2\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Ah! I got it, thank you for the help!

Comment: You're very welcome.